# Does a proper prior lead always a proper posterior?

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior

Does a proper prior lead always a proper posterior?

I cannot check whether the posterior is proper, so I was wondering if this assumption is always satisfied .

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87321/  And Tom Minka's answer there is an answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but Tom Minka said that if data is continuos even if the prior is proper, the posterior may be improper. What if data is discrete?