# Proper prior leading to improper posterior

Tags: bayesian, posterior

## Preface

I must say I am aware of previous discussions (e.g. [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87321/does-the-bayesian-posterior-need-to-be-a-proper-distribution)) and also of this excellent, [didactic proof](https://youtu.be/SPRnFY8J_GI?t=304) using Fubini's theorem as presented by Jared Niemi [I'm not saying Jared Niemi is the originator of said proof, mind you]. 
But I have been thinking about an example where we have a likelihood with variable support and a proper prior and the posterior is improper. I do not claim to have discovered anything new; I'm most likely missing something obvious and would be grateful if someone could point out to me where my "counter-example" below fails.

### The supposed counter-example

This is supposed to be a counter-example to the assertion "if the prior $\pi(\theta)$ is proper then the posterior $p(\theta \mid y)$ will be proper almost surely".

Let $p(y | \theta) = \frac{2y}{\theta}, \theta > 0,  y \in [0, \sqrt{\theta}]$. It seems to me this likelihood is a proper distribution over $y$: it's non-negative and integrates to unity over the support. The slight quirk is that the support depends on the parameter. This is the case for instance for the [GEV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) too. Now suppose I place a standard half-Cauchy prior on $\theta$, $ \pi(\theta) = 2/\pi(1 + \theta^2), \theta > 0$. It seems to me that the posterior $p(\theta \mid y)$ is not integrable w.r.t. $\theta$:
$$ \int_0^{+\infty} p(\theta \mid y) d\theta = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{2y}{\theta} \frac{2}{\pi \left( 1 + \theta^2 \right)} d\theta = \frac{4y}{\pi} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\theta(1+\theta)^2} d\theta = \infty.$$

If someone could point out what I'm missing here, I'd be grateful.

### What is wrong

The limits of integration (see Robin's answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The likelihood you are using is actually
$$p(y|\theta)=\frac{2y}{\theta}\mathbb I_{\{0\leq y \leq \sqrt \theta\}}.$$
You didn't include the indicator in your posterior calculation. The actual posterior is defined by 
$$p(\theta|y)\propto \frac{2}{\pi(1+\theta^2)}\frac{2y}{\theta}\mathbb I_{\{\theta\geq y^2\}}.$$

The lower limit on your integral is thus wrong: the integral of the posterior is actually
$$\int_{y^2}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(1+\theta^2)}\frac{2y}{\theta} \,d\theta = \frac{4y}{\pi}\int_{y^2}^\infty \frac{1}{\theta(1+\theta^2)}\,d\theta = \frac{2y}{\pi}\left(\log(y^4+1)-4\log y\right)$$
which is finite as long as $y>0$, hence the posterior is proper almost surely.

Comment: There is no possibility that a proper prior leads to an improper posterior.

Comment: I know, @Xi'an. It's just that I was confused about what I was doing wrong in this particular example. The proof I linked, which uses Fubini's theorem, assumes the likelihood to be proper. This is almost always the case, but I wonder how you go about proving propriety when the likelihood is no longer integrable over the data space (e.g. the so-called "power priors").

Comment: Using powered likelihoods is open to this danger of the posterior not being defined, simply because some forms of powered likelihoods are no longer integrable in $x$, the data. This means case-by-case examination must be conducted to ensure the posterior doth exist.

Comment: @Xi'an Do you have a canonical example of a powered likelihood and proper prior leading to an improper posterior?

Comment: @RobinRyder: euh, not immediately...!

Comment: @Xi'an I've created a question about this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370919/can-a-proper-prior-and-exponentiated-likelihood-lead-to-an-improper-posterior

Comment: @Xi'an (and whomever might be interested): in the associated thread we actually find a proof that tempered likelihoods actually lead to proper posteriors. InfProbSci provides a proof for exponents between 0 and 1 and I then give a way of extending the idea to powers > 1.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this argument when it appeared and agrees with it!